# MySQL Between is not grabbing the end date?

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM orders WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2012-07-30' AND '2012-07-30'
```

It returns 0 results, although there's 1000+ entries for date `2012-07-30`.
I found out that the `BETWEEN` simply does not grab the END date, so if it was

```
BETWEEN '2012-07-28' AND '2012-07-30'
```

...it should grab me entries for 28, 29 but not 30.

How can I make it to take the end date itself too?

Comment: why don't you simply use WHERE date_created= '2012-07-30'

Comment: this might sound stupid, but can't you add a day in the "end" date? Like BETWEEN '2012-07-28' AND '2012-07-31'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell it the end of the day instead of the beginning.

```
'2012-07-30 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Perfect answer, so that was why!

Answer (score 2):

Never use `BETWEEN` with dates (and especially with datetimes). You can use:

```
WHERE date_created >= '2012-07-30' 
  AND date_created < '2012-07-31' 
---or:             < '2012-07-30' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
-------------------^-------------- notice the lack of the equal sign here
```

which works equally well with `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` datatypes.

Notice that you may still miss some rows with the proposed solution of `BETWEEN '2012-07-30'  AND '2012-07-30 23:59:59'`.

For detailed explanations, read this nice blog post:

**[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**

The blog discusses SQL-Server issues but most parts about `BETWEEN` apply to MySQL as well (except for the not yet existing milli-second support, thanx @Ignacio for the correction).

Comment: An excellent point in general, but [slightly less relevant with MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fractional-seconds.html).

Comment: @Ignacio: Yes, you are right in that. But it's good to have code that will not break when [millisecond support will be added](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/microseconds-in-mariadb/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a day to the end date in your query:

```
  BETWEEN('2012-07-28', DATE_ADD('2012-07-30', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply use

... WHERE date_created= '2012-07-30'

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more info
between do exactly this (min <= expr AND expr <= max) ,got it from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

as others pointed out, you missed the time, and its better be a timestamp unless the date is used for things like birthdate